# React/Gatsby: Using CSS grid with alternating number of columns in each row

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid, gatsby

I'm trying to create a grid layout that alternates the number of columns in each row. So, for example, the first row would have one column and the second row would have two columns then the third row would go back to one column. At this point, I only have a grid that has two columns for each row.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to do this? Thanks!

Here's what I have now:

```
<div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-10">
  {projects.map(({ node }, index) => {
    const title = node.frontmatter.title || node.fields.slug
    const client = node.frontmatter.client
    const category = node.frontmatter.category
    const image = node.frontmatter.image.childImageSharp.fluid
    const description = node.frontmatter.description

    return (
      <div className="col-span-1">
        <Link to={node.fields.slug}>
          <BgImg fluid={image} className="h-104 bg-cover bg-no-repeat flex flex-col justify-end hover:shadow-2xl transition-all ease-linear duration-300" key={node.id}>
          </BgImg>
        </Link>
        <div className="py-5">
          <h3 className="text-2xl font-regular"><span className="font-semibold">{client}</span><span className="mx-1">&mdash;</span>{title}</h3>
          <p className="text-xl mb-4 font-light">{description}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  })}
</div>
```

Comment: It will be very short, use modulo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to have the 1-column rows span the whole width like this:

```
[content] [content]
[      content    ]
[content] [content]
```

Rather than like this:

```
[content] [content]
[content]
[content] [content]
```

Then this should be fairly simple to accomplish in TailwindCSS like this:

```
<div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-10">
  {projects.map(({ node }, index) => {
    const title = node.frontmatter.title || node.fields.slug
    const client = node.frontmatter.client
    const category = node.frontmatter.category
    const image = node.frontmatter.image.childImageSharp.fluid
    const description = node.frontmatter.description

    return (
      <div className={index % 3 == 2 ? "col-span-2" : "col-span-1"}>
        <Link to={node.fields.slug}>
          <BgImg fluid={image} className="h-104 bg-cover bg-no-repeat flex flex-col justify-end hover:shadow-2xl transition-all ease-linear duration-300" key={node.id}>
          </BgImg>
        </Link>
        <div className="py-5">
          <h3 className="text-2xl font-regular"><span className="font-semibold">{client}</span><span className="mx-1">&mdash;</span>{title}</h3>
          <p className="text-xl mb-4 font-light">{description}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  })}
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is perfect! Thank you! This is a much cleaner solution than what i came up with

Comment: @taylor018 Glad it works! Could you please accept my answer if it's correct?